# Syntax error in my user defined function?

Tags: sql-server

I creating a function and I have a red error line under the `BEGIN` keyword and I can't figure out what is wrong with this query?

```
USE PR
GO

CREATE FUNCTION fnInsCosts
    (@NoDependents int)
RETURNS TABLE
BEGIN
    RETURN 
        (SELECT 
             EmpName, 
             SUM(BaseCost) AS TotBaseCost, 
             SUM(SpouseIns) AS TotSpouseCost, 
             SUM(DepIns) AS TotDepCost, 
             SUM(DentalCost) AS TotDentalCost,
             SUM(SUM(BaseCost) + SUM(SpouseIns) + SUM(DepIns) + SUM(DentalCost)) AS TotalInsCost
         FROM 
             vwPayroll
         WHERE 
             Dependants = @NoDependents
         GROUP BY 
             EmpName)
END;
```

Comment: For one thing, stored functions should always have the schema qualifier - e.g. `CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnInsCosts` - including when you're calling them

Comment: Is this a new practice? My textbook which is sql server 2016 doesn't show it written this way?

Comment: No - well established, long time best practice - nothing new

Comment: You missed the AS keyword. That was the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnInsCosts
    (@NoDependents int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
    SELECT EmpName, SUM(BaseCost) AS TotBaseCost, SUM(SpouseIns) AS TotSpouseCost
        , SUM(DepIns) AS TotDepCost, SUM(DentalCost) AS TotDentalCost
        , SUM(SUM(BaseCost) + SUM(SpouseIns) + SUM(DepIns) + SUM(DentalCost)) AS TotalInsCost
    FROM vwPayroll
    WHERE Dependants = @NoDependents
    GROUP BY EmpName
)
```

Comment: This seemed to work? Why would it though I've written a few of these functions like my OP and no issues?

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: `Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fnInsCosts, Line 8 [Batch Start Line 9]
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
Invalid object name 'dbo.fnInsCosts'.`

Comment: ok, that's a different error then. i was answering why there was a "red error line under the BEGIN keyword".

Comment: Ok sorry you are right thank you!. You mind helping with this one though lol, I'm pretty confused, and don't want to waste all my questions

Comment: it's to do with your SUM(SUM()) . not sure why you're doing a SUM of a SUM. try getting rid of that and see how you go.